# How to compare dates and change values in another column by groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have two data frames,

```
ID           DATE         EVENT
300-1-003    2019-07-14   4
300-1-004    2019-10-27   4
300-1-004    2019-10-29   4
300-1-008    2019-10-11   4


ID           DATE         EVENT
300-1-001    2019-10-22   0
300-1-002    2019-10-02   0
300-1-004    2019-10-27   0
300-1-004    2019-10-30   0
300-1-008    2019-10-11   0
```

I want to change the value in EVENT column in the first data frame to 1 if the DATE are the same for the same ID in both data frames.

I tried to do it with

```
df1$EVENT= ifelse(df1$DATE=df2$DATE & df1$ID=df2$ID, 1, 4)
```

Also have tried using filter to fit out the same date first..

```
df2_2= filter(df1$DATE=df2$DATE)
```

But I got error as below for the second method and the first method just doesn't work...

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "df2_2= filter(df1$DATE="
```

Both class(df1$DATE) and class(df2$DATE) are "Date". 
My desired result would be like

```
ID           DATE         EVENT
300-1-003    2019-07-14   4
300-1-004    2019-10-27   1
300-1-004    2019-10-29   4
300-1-008    2019-10-11   4
```

I have searched how to compare dates.. I assume I could compare it this way?
I have stuck for hours, I guess I just wouldn't figure out how to do it.. I would appreciate any help....

Comment: Wouldn't the last row be also `1` because '2019-10-11', '300-1-008' matches in both datasets

Comment: Yes, it should be. Sorry for the typo, and thank you for the answer! it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join `on` the 'DATE' and 'ID' columns and assign (`:=`) the 'EVENT' in 'df1' to 1

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2,  EVENT := 1, on = .(DATE, ID)]
```

---

Also, the `ifelse` can be changed to

```
with(df1, ifelse(DATE %in% df2$DATE & ID %in% df2$ID, 1, EVENT))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("300-1-003", "300-1-004", "300-1-004", 
"300-1-008"), DATE = c("2019-07-14", "2019-10-27", "2019-10-29", 
"2019-10-11"), EVENT = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("300-1-001", "300-1-002", "300-1-004", 
"300-1-004", "300-1-008"), DATE = c("2019-10-22", "2019-10-02", 
"2019-10-27", "2019-10-30", "2019-10-11"), EVENT = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question while I'm trying to use this for others.. I want to change BUN of GS_new2 to the value of BUN of GS_TNA_1 if the DATE and ID are matched, setDT(GS_new2)[GS_TNA_1, BUN:=GS_TNA_1$BUN, on=.(DATE, ID)], but I got Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(setDT(GS_new2), GS_TNA_1, `:=`(BUN, GS_TNA_1$BUN),  :
  Supplied 118 items to be assigned to 145 items of column 'BUN' (recycled leaving remainder of 27 items).   ----> I know in GS_new2 there would be multiple rows would match each row in GS_TNA_1. Is it because of this? If yes, how could I fix it..

Comment: @user10301352  I think you need `i.BUN` instead of `GS_TNA_1$BUN` as this selecting the entire column instead of the joined values

Comment: Thank you.. is there a way to do subtraction as well? setDT(GS2_ID1)[GS2_ID0, result:=GS2_ID0$TIME -GS2_ID1$TIME, on=.(DATE, ID)] I want it to subtract the two columns if the DATE and ID matched and fill in result column, I'm getting warning for this too..I think it's probably the same problem you mentioned above..but I just wouldn't solve it.. I would also appreciate any references to help me comprehensive  this function! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need `i.TIME - TIME`

Comment: I think this part about subtraction could be a separate question to avoid confusion :)